# GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName always returning -1

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Trying to call `GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName` to get color of windows 10 notifcation area.
But it always returns -1

```
    typedef int(WINAPI*pGetImmersiveColorTypeFromName)(char* name);
    const pGetImmersiveColorTypeFromName GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName = (pGetImmersiveColorTypeFromName)GetProcAddress(hModule, (LPCSTR)96);
    if (GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName)
    {
        colorType = GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName("ImmersiveApplicationTextDarkTheme");
    }
```

I have tried heaps of other names but always get -1

Comment: What is the contract for `GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName`? What are valid inputs? Where is the documentation?

Comment: there is no documetation, it is in `"uxtheme.dll"` and i checked the function in ida free, i have seen this used in c# and it works fine.

Comment: @ramafe Is it possible that `GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName` wants a wide string? Try `GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName(L"ImmersiveApplicationTextDarkTheme");`

Comment: @MichaelWalz lol yes that was it, i tried it before, but must od messed it up. I set it as a void* to get it to work

Comment: @ramafe your mentioning "I've seen this in c#" made me think of wide strings as in C# strings are wide strings. I'll post this as an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName` wants a wide string, so change the declaration from `char*` to `wchar_t*`:

```
typedef int(WINAPI*pGetImmersiveColorTypeFromName)(wchar_t* name);
const pGetImmersiveColorTypeFromName GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName = (pGetImmersiveColorTypeFromName)GetProcAddress(hModule, (LPCSTR)96);
if (GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName)
{
    colorType = GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName(L"ImmersiveApplicationTextDarkTheme");
}
```

Comment: `L"ImmersiveApplicationTextDarkTheme"` is of type `const wchar_t[34]`. Even though the symbol is exported using C name mangling (which doesn't contain type information), the correct function pointer signature is `int(WINAPI* pGetImmersiveColorTypeFromName)(const wchar_t*)`.

Comment: For more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865923/windows-10-taskbar-color-detection-for-tray-icon/56867641#56867641