# Windows 10 taskbar color detection for tray icon

Tags: c#, windows

Is there any way to detect which color and which type of windows style windows 10 is running one (the latest one I guess which has light/dark theme - 1903)

I have a tray icon app and would like to display a black/white icon depending on the theme. The built in apps show them properly, but I do not know how to detect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get current Theme information from the registry :

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes**

(the **GetCurrentThemeName** api returns *InstallVisualStyle* value on my Windows 10 OS)

Declaration :

```
[DllImport("UxTheme.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetCurrentThemeName(StringBuilder pszThemeFileName, int cchMaxNameChars, StringBuilder pszColorBuff, int cchMaxColorChars, StringBuilder pszSizeBuff, int cchMaxSizeChars);
```

To get the current Theme color (Accent color), you can do :

```
[DllImport("Uxtheme.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "#95")]
public static extern int GetImmersiveColorFromColorSetEx(int dwImmersiveColorSet, int dwImmersiveColorType, bool bIgnoreHighContrast, int dwHighContrastCacheMode);

[DllImport("Uxtheme.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "#96")]
public static extern int GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName(IntPtr pName);

[DllImport("Uxtheme.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "#98")]
public static extern int GetImmersiveUserColorSetPreference(bool bForceCheckRegistry, bool bSkipCheckOnFail);

int nColorSystemAccent = GetImmersiveColorFromColorSetEx(GetImmersiveUserColorSetPreference(false, false), GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName(Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("ImmersiveSystemAccent")), false, 0);
System.Drawing.Color colorSystemAccent = ColorTranslator.FromWin32(nColorSystemAccent);
// Test color
this.BackColor = colorSystemAccent;
```

Comment: Thanks for setting me on this path! It seems to me that Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\SystemUsesLightTheme is the exact key I need to know whether to use light or dark icons.

Comment: GetImmersiveColorTypeFromName() is not exported anymore in UxTheme.dll. Use GetProcAddress(hUxTheme,MAKEINTRESOURCEA(96)) instead.

Comment: I suppose you copied this code from another page without understanding it. Whatever this code is supposed to do it does not return the color of the taskbar and so does not answer the question.